# how to show 3 or more form accoring to the aarays of json type in react Js for building daynamic form

Tags: json, reactjs, components

const fields = {
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'group',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Name',
    group_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Address',
    group_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    type: 'text',
    label: 'City',
    value: 'Lahore',
    group_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    type: 'text',
    label: 'State',
    value: 'Punjab',
    group_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Country',
    value: 'Pakistan',
    group_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    type: 'group',
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    type: 'date',
    label: 'Date of birth',
    group_id: 7
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    type: 'email',
    label: 'Email',
    group_id: 7
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    type: 'phone',
    label: 'Phone',
    group_id: 7
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    type: 'color',
    label: 'Color',
    value: '#ff9900',
    group_id: 7
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Age',
    value: 22,
    group_id: 7
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Friends',
    value: 3,
    group_id: 7
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    type: 'select_one',
    label: 'Select One City',
    value: 'karachi',
    choices: ['lahore', 'karachi', 'multan', 'faisalabad', 'pishawar', 'queta', 'islamabad']
    group_id: 7
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    type: 'select_one',
    label: 'Select One Fruit',
    value: 'peach',
    choices: ['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'peach', 'grapes', 'pine', 'strawberry']
    group_id: 7
  }
}

Comment: You can use a json linter to figure this out... Try google.

Comment: i am try but no solution.you tell me how to solve it.

Comment: Step 1: www.google.com - Step 2: type json linter and hit enter... - Step 3: Use the linter. Good luck!

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: following Error How To resolve it ?Error: Parse error on line 1:
const fields = { {  id: 
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct sytnax of your JSON Object.

```
 [ 
 { "id": 1,
   "type": "group" 

 },
 { 
  "id": 2,
  "type": "text",
  "label": "Name",
  "group_id": 1 
 },
 { "id": 3,
   "type": "text",
   "label": "Address", 
   "group_id": 1   
},
{ "id": 4,
  "type": "text",
  "label": "City",
  "value": "Lahore",
  "group_id": 1 
}, 
{  "id": 5,
   "type": "text", 
   "label": "State", 
   "value": "Punjab",
   "group_id": 1 
}, 
{ "id": 6,
"type": "text", 
"label": "Country", 
"value": "Pakistan",
"group_id": 1
}, 
{ 
  "id": 7, 
  "type": "group"
},
{ 
  "id": 8, 
  "type": "date",
  "label": "Date of birth",
  "group_id": 7 

},
{ "id": 9, 
  "type": "email", 
  "label": "Email",
  "group_id": 7 
}, 
{ 
  "id": 10, 
  "type": "phone", 
  "label": "Phone", 
  "group_id": 7 

}, 
{ 
  "id": 11, 
  "type": "color", 
  "label": "Color", 
  "value": "#ff9900", 
  "group_id": 7
},
{ 
  "id": 12, 
  "type": "number", 
  "label": "Age", 
  "value": 22, 
  "group_id": 7 
}, 
{ 
  "id": 13, 
  "type": "number", 
  "label": "Friends", 
  "value": 3, 
  "group_id": 7 

}, 
{ "id": 14,
  "type": "select_one", 
  "label": "Select One City", 
  "value": "karachi", 
  "choices": [
               "lahore", 
               "karachi", 
               "multan", 
               "faisalabad", 
               "pishawar", 
               "queta",
               "islamabad"
             ], 
  "group_id": 7 

}, 
{ 
  "id": 15, 
  "type": "select_one", 
  "label": "Select One Fruit", 
  "value":"peach", 
  "choices": [
                "apple", 
                "banana", 
                "mango", 
                "peach", 
                "grapes", 
                "pine", 
                "strawberry"], 
  "group_id": 7 } 
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not JSON.

Firstly

> JSON objects are written in key/value pairs.

This is not written in key-value pairs.

> Keys must be strings

Keys are not strings in your question, also you should use double quotes and not single quotes.

Thirdly,

> Each key/value pair is separated by a comma

You don't put commas if there is no key-value pair after the coma. An example of JSON would be 
`{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }`

Refer [Mozilla's guide on JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

You can use [JSON Editor Online](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) to check for errors in your JSON

Comment: how i access json key value pair in my form in ReactJs

Comment: I didn't understand your question, is it related to this question? as to how to create key value pairs?

Comment: How i access JSON object in json for like if i have three groups other is outside like group 200,300,400,500,600 what's i doing my outside group came in the any group which have i set the logic.     so i have asking you why i make a logic if i click the group 1 or group 2 or group 3 the group 200,300,400,500,600 can set in the group 1 2 and three according to the requirments,using states and filter, also  note: i have make a form daynamicaly from JSON fields